# Spring JPA and Streaming - Is the data fetched incrementally?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am looking at [streaming query results](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming) section of the Spring documentation. Does this functionality fetch all the data at once but provide it as a stream? Or does it fetch data incrementally so that it will be more memory efficient?

If it doesn't fetch data incrementally, is there any other way to achieve this with spring data jpa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your platform.

> Instead of simply wrapping the query results in a Stream data store specific methods are used to perform the streaming.

With MySQL for example the streaming is performed in a [truly streaming fashion](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-mysql-result-set-streaming-perform-vs-fetching-the-whole-jdbc-resultset-at-once/), but of course if the underlying datastore (or the driver being used) doesn't have support for such a mechanism (yet) it won't make a difference.

MySQL is IIRC currently the only driver that can provide streaming without additional configuration in this fashion whereas other databases/drivers go with the standard fetch size setting as described by the venerable Vlad Mihalcea here: https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-stream-the-result-of-a-query-execution/, note the trade-off between performance vs. memory use. Other databases are most likely going to need a [reactive database client](https://r2dbc.io/) in order to even perform true streaming.

Whatever the underlying streaming method, what affects most is how you process the stream. Using Spring's `StreamingResponseBody` for example would allow you to stream large amounts of data directly from the database to the client with minimal memory use. Still it's a very specific use case, so don't start streaming everything just yet unless you're sure it's worth it.

Comment: What about Oracle? Also, can you mention a few well known databases that don't support this?